# se puede actualizar una determinada fila de una tabla dentro de un trigger dirigido a la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, trigger

Adjunto esta consulta SQL de un trigger , la cual consta de dos tablas separadas pero que el llenado de la tabla almacén debe afectar a la tabla producto en el campo de stock. El conflicto sucede al actualizar la tabla almacén

aquí adjunto mi diagrama de tablas para su análisis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí adjunto mi consulta SQL para su análisis:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `control`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `TI_almacen`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `TI_almacen` AFTER INSERT ON `almacen` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE _id_producto INT;

    DECLARE _stock_caja INT;
    DECLARE _stock_botella INT;
    DECLARE _cantidad_caja INT;
    DECLARE _cantidad_botella INT;

    SET _id_producto = new.id_producto;
    SET _cantidad_caja = new.cantidad_caja;
    SET _cantidad_botella = new.cantidad_botella;


    SELECT a.stock_cajas, a.stock_botellas 
    INTO _stock_caja, _stock_botella
    FROM almacen a ORDER BY a.id_producto = _id_producto DESC LIMIT 1;

    UPDATE almacen SET stock_cajas=(_stock_caja+_cantidad_caja),stock_botellas=(_stock_caja+_cantidad_botella)
                WHERE id_almacen=(SELECT id_almacen FROM almacen ORDER BY id_almacen DESC LIMIT 1);

    UPDATE producto
        SET     cantidad_caja=(_stock_caja+_cantidad_caja),
            cantidad_botella=(_stock_caja+_cantidad_botella)
                WHERE id_producto=_id_producto;
    /*cajas =10 + new caja 10 0 total cajas pilsen 20
    botella = 120  new botella = 10 total botellas pilsen 130   */

    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿dicho *trigger* al ejecutarlo te devuelve algún error?

Comment: ¿Nos pasas el dataset (phpMyAdmin/Exportar) con algún dato de prueba para intentar reproducir y depurar el error?